# The sum of integers

Tags: java

I would like to print the sum of all integers from `a to b` containing both. So far I have stopped at this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int j = b-a;
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<=j ; i++){
            total+=i;
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Run it through your debugger and step through the code, especially the loop to see exactly what your code is doing

Comment: You can also debug-print using `System.out.println`. I think it would be a very good exercise for you to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let b=200 and a=195, so according to your logic j=(200-195)=5. With the loop, the sum will be 1+2+3+4+5=15. But you need sum of 195+196+197+198+199+200.

The loop should go as:

```
 for(int i = a; i<=b ; i++){
        total+=i;
    }
```

To understand how to debug a program please refer to https://techforhumans.site/java/right-way-to-debug-code-using-pen-and-paper/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = a; i<=b ; i++){
            total+=i;
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
```

Of course this works only if a < b

Comment: You can use `Math.max` and `Math.min` to create a solution that works for all numbers

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually adding the integers between the `a` and `b` - you're adding all of the integers from `0` to `a - b`. Your loop should actually be from `a` to `b`, not `0` to `a - b`.

Consider the case where `a` is 5 and `b` is 10 - you should be adding 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10, but instead your current algorithm adds 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5.